# Problems with Vendor:Publish in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, package, laravel-5, vendor

I downloaded a package with composer. In this case the package is Riari Forum-Laravel. When I run `php artisan vendor:publish`, it says there is nothing to publish and I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

To make Laravel aware that you have installed a package you need to tell the framework that. So open your `config/app.php` and add the forum package to your packages array:

```
'Riari\Forum\ForumServiceProvider',
```

After that you can do the publish command.

Answer (score 3):

This always happens because Laravel cannot find the required references from your optimized/cached loader files.

Once you add the vendor's class to `config/app.php`, I have a script that runs:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan optimize (optional)
```

Post this, running `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="xyz"` will definitely work.

Comment: `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="xyz" ` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I do:

php artisan config:clear

then:

php artisan vendor:publish

next in my case:

php artisan my_migration_name:migration

Answer (score 0):

are you using cashed config files ?

try using php artisan config:clear and retry php artisan vendor:publish

when your config files are cached any change to it will not be applied until you clear the config cache.